# What resources can direct me to real estate with landing strips?

Tags: airport, usa

I am looking for a website or places to look at estate / personal residences in PA, DE, MD, VA that have landing strips already in place.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be many, however, some of those "landing strips already in place" will no doubt be public airports that border the property or shared private community strips that aren't generally inviting the public.

1. [aviationacres.com](http://www.aviationacres.com/)
2. [aviationhomes.com](http://www.aviationhomes.com/)
3. [hangarnetwork.com](https://www.hangarnetwork.com/)
4. [airportairparkhomes.com](http://airportairparkhomes.com/)